# All possible combinations of matrices with values from vectors

Tags: r, matrix, vector, combinations

How to get all possible 2 by v matrices, where v is the number of vectors with arbitrary length, filled with the values of a vector.

For instance, I got three vectors `A = c(1,2,3)` `B = c("x","z")` `C = c(1,0)`.

Suppose now, I want to get all possible 2 by 3 matrices or data frames which stem from the values of the above vectors.

In the end, I would like to have something like this:

```
       combination_id first_row A B C
    1:              1         1 0 x 0
    2:              2         0 1 x 1
    3:              3         1 1 z 0
    4:              4         0 0 z 1
    5:              5         1 0 x 0
    6:              6         0 1 x 0
    7:              :               
    8:              :
```

Comment: expand.grid(A,B,C)?

Comment: what are x and z in the desired output (column B)? because they are not in the 3 vectors A, B, C

Comment: sorry, just a typo

Comment: with expand.grid i get all 12 combinations, but I want 12^2 combinations where each is,e.g., a 2 row matrix. So basically expand.grid(A,B,C,A,B,C) but not in a wide format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives every possible combination of two elements from each set (where replacement is allowed), giving a total of 144 matrices. These are then bound together to give a single 288-row data frame:

```r
A = c(1,2,3) 
B = c("x","z") 
C = c(1,0)

df <- setNames(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, 
      lapply(as.data.frame(t(expand.grid(A, B, C, A, B, C))), 
             matrix, nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE))), 
      c("A", "B", "C"))

head(df)
#>   A B C
#> 1 1 x 1
#> 2 1 x 1
#> 3 2 x 1
#> 4 1 x 1
#> 5 3 x 1
#> 6 1 x 1

nrow(df)
#> [1] 288
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>